# Tika--Extracting Distinct Items from a Compound Document

Tags: apache-tika

**Question:**
Assume an email message with an attachment (assume a JPEG attachment). How do I parse (not using the Tika facade classes) the email message and return the distinct pieces--a) the email text contents and b) the email attachment?

**Configuration:**
Tika 1.2
Java 1.7

**Details:**
I have been able to properly parse email messages in basic email message formats. However, after the parsing, I need to know a) the email's text contents and b) the the contents of any attachment to the email. I will store these items in my database as essentially parent email with child attachments.

What I cannot figure out is how I can "get back" the distinct parts and know that the parent email has attachments and be able to separately store those attachments referenced to the mail. This is, I believe, essentially similar to extracting ZipFile contents.

**Code Example:**

```
 private Message processDocument(String fullfilepath) {
     try {
         File filename = new File(fullfilepath) ;
         return this.processDocument(filename) ;
     } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
        Message error = new Message(false) ;
         error.appendErrorMessage("The file name was null.") ;
         return error ;
     } 
 }

private Message processDocument(File filename) {
    InputStream stream = null;
    try {
       stream = new FileInputStream(filename) ;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        fnfe.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("FileNotFoundException") ;
        return diag ;
    }

int writelimit = -1 ; 
ContentHandler texthandler = new BodyContentHandler(writelimit); 
this.safehandlerbodytext = new SafeContentHandler(texthandler);
this.meta = new Metadata() ;
ParseContext context = new ParseContext() ;

AutoDetectParser autodetectparser = new AutoDetectParser() ;

try {

    autodetectparser.parse(
        stream,
        texthandler,
        meta,
        context) ;

    this.documenttype = meta.get("Content-Type") ;

    diag.setSuccessful(true);

} catch (IOException ioe) {
    // if the document stream could not be read
    System.out.println("TikaTextExtractorHelper IOException " + ioe.getMessage()) ;
    //FIXME -- add real handling

} catch (SAXException se) {
    // if the SAX events could not be processed
    System.out.println("TikaTextExtractorHelper SAXException " + se.getMessage()) ;
  //FIXME -- add real handling

} catch (TikaException te) {
    // if the document could not be parsed
    System.out.println("TikaTextExtractorHelper TikaException " + te.getMessage()) ;
    System.out.println("Exception Filename = " + filename.getName()) ;
  //FIXME -- add real handling

}
```

}

Comment: Have you looked at adding a parser to the context, which grabs the child documents and saves them out?

Comment: Thank you. No, I have not tried this. I am not too familiar with what the Context actually does. If I understand your note, I can add another/different parser to the Context itself? How does this return the child results? I will try to look into this further.

Answer (score 1):

When Tika hits an embedded document, it goes to the ParseContext to see if you have supplied a recursing parser. If you have, it'll use that to process any embedded resources. If you haven't, it'll skip.

So, what you probably want to do is something like:

```
public static class HandleEmbeddedParser extends AbstractParser {
   public List<File> found = new ArrayList<File>();
   Set<MediaType> getSupportedTypes(ParseContext context) {
       // Return what you want to handle
       HashSet<MediaType> types = new HashSet<MediaType>();
       types.put(MediaType.application("pdf"));
       types.put(MediaType.application("zip"));
       return types;
   }
   void parse(
        InputStream stream, ContentHandler handler,
        Metadata metadata, ParseContext context
   ) throws IOException {
       // Do something with the child documents
       // eg save to disk
       File f = File.createTempFile("tika","tmp");
       found.add(f);

       FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(f);
       IOUtils.copy(stream,fout);
       fout.close();
   }
}

ParseContext context = new ParseContext();
context.set(Parser.class, new HandleEmbeddedParser();
parser.parse(....);
```

Comment: First, thank you. 
Second, I am still puzzled regarding where the recursion comes in. I went back and started over looking at the SAX model (I am not familiar with SAX) and going from there. I believe I am reaching a slightly better understanding of how the Tika parts fit together (SAX understanding is a key element).
Third, sometimes I just do something hyper-stupid. The whole issue arose because Tika did not appear to be properly parsing email attachments. However, as I later found out, my small test data set had encrypted (PGP) emails. This is why my attachments looked unparsed.

Comment: When Tika hits an embedded document, it gives that to the parser (if there is one) on your `ParseContext` for processing